# Surface Estimation

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, curve, surface, data-fitting

TL;DR - How do I only analyse the surface data points for surface estimation?

I have a 3D object, and I would like to estimate the surface shape.

The problem is: MATLAB curve fitting toolbox takes into account all the data points of the object.  See the example of a cylinder and it's approximated polynomial.  MATLAB is taking into account all the data points for surface estimation, what can I do to over come this?

[image: Cylinder Estimation]

Comment: what you need is an algorithm to fit a surface mesh to your data points. Maybe mesh growing?

Comment: Thank you for this information @Anthony. I have had a quick google and will continue to investigate 'mesh growing'.
However, I would like to know if you are aware of a specific MATLAB or Python function that can help me do this?

Comment: you can try [delaunay](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html), but it is likely to generate tetrahedron inside/under the surface.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the outer and inner surface have identical shape, you can first do an `imfill` to make the object solid and then use morphological skeleton, `bwmorph(BW,'skel',Inf)` to turn it into a single line, which you then can approximate the shape from.

Comment: I believe the question is dealing with a set of points in 3D rather than a 2D image. I'm not sure how `imfill` could be useful here?

Comment: Even though the points are in 3D, couldn't you just consider 2 slices and then piece it back together? The idea of using `imfill` is to make the object solid, so that the entire structure are thinned out (in?). If you applied skeleton to the figure directly you would still have all the points in the middle.

Comment: What would be the first input argument in `imfill`? The function requires an [binary image](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html#buo3g4l-1-BW) or a [grayscale image](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html#buo3g4l-1-I)?

Comment: Thank you Nick Mattsson for your help and information.  I have solved it, and annoyingly my solution is computationally very expensive - unlike your clean suggestion of using morphology.